# ContextBroker Crashed

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

ContextBroker has been working fine for the past few days, I made a 12M subscription to orion a couple of days ago, and it decided to die this morning, noone even touched the computer at 6am when the last message was received. So when I checked the status it said:

```
contextBroker dead but pid file exists
```

So I just init.d started it again. Any solution to this occurrence?

**Edit1** Here is the log file from that day (sorry for late response):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tl0n3u8kwzlyat/ContextBrokerLog?dl=0

It was stored as contextBroker.log.old inside the /var/log/contextBroker directory, maybe because I created new subscriptions since then.

Comment: Have you tried to find a log file?

Comment: yes, and I have no idea where it is, could you navigate me? I will then copy the contents in the post

Comment: Hava a look to https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Log_file. Typically it is at /tmp/contextBroker.log (default value) or /var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log (the default one when Orion runs as service).

Comment: @fgalan I updated my question with a link of the log file